# How to copy a cell with a mention to another cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

I have 2 spreadsheets.

In the first I have a column filled with the values made by @mention as shown in the image below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw8Nv.png)

The second spreadsheet I use to receive this data through a script.

Script:

```
function show(){

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("BDCP");
const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Campaigns");

   let lastRow = sheet2.getLastRow();
   let bd = sheet1.getRange("B2:C50").getValues();
   let cp = sheet2.getRange("B15:B50").getValues();

   for(var row = 0; row < bd.length; row++){
     if(bd[row][0] == "ACTIVE"){
        const row = row + 2;
        const key = sheet1.getRange("C"+ line).getValue();
        const rowCampaign = row + 15;
        sheet2.getRange(rowCampaign, 2).setValue(key);
     }
   }
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't copy the cell with @mention, but only the content.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNfSe.png)

How do I make it copy the content exactly while keeping the @mention?

Comment: I've never tried it but it may be possible with [richText](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value)

Comment: Where is `linhaCampaign` defined?

Comment: In your script, I think that `line` is not declared, and an error occurs at `const row = row + 2;` because `row` has already been declared, and `linhaCampaign` is not declared (this has already been mentioned in a comment). But you say `The problem is that it doesn't copy the cell with @mention, but only the content.`. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your current script. How about this? By the way, in your actual situation, you want to copy only rows that column "B" has "ACTIVE". Is my understanding correct? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: By the way, the column of the smart chips is only column "C" of "BDCP" sheet in your actual situation?

Answer (score 1):

**Recommended: Use copyTo() instead of setValues()**

```
copyTo() will copy the text including the format.

You can refer to this sample code below:

function show(){

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("BDCP");

const sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Campaigns");

let lastRow = sheet2.getLastRow();

let bd = sheet1.getRange("B2:C50");

let cp = sheet2.getRange("B15:B50");

bd.copyTo(sheet2.getRange("B15:B50"));

}
```

Note: I am unable to run your code as there are some variables that is not defined.

Sample output:

[image] [image] **Reference:**

- [copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination)